# Do we have vertical partitioning in mongodb...?

Tags: mysql, mongodb

I know that we have horizontal distribution of data in mongo db using the concept of sharding.
sharding is basically horizontal partitioning of data.
how about vertical partitioning of data. Is is possible to partition data in mongodb as we can do in MYSQL....?

Thanks in advance.
Regards,
UDAY

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/databases/mongodb/9781430230519/sharding/partitioning_horizontal_and_vertical_dat (incidentally the first result when I googled this):

> Partitioning Data Vertically
>
> In the traditional view of databases, data is stored in rows and columns. Vertical partitioning consists of breaking up a record on column boundaries and storing the parts in
> separate tables or collections. It can be argued that a relational
> database design that uses joined tables with a one-to-one relationship
> is a form of co-resident vertical data partitioning.  **MongoDB,
> however, does not lend itself to this form of partitioning because the
> structure of its records (documents) does not fit the nice and tidy
> row and column model.** Therefore, there are few opportunities to
> cleanly separate a row based on its column boundaries. MongoDB also
> promotes the use of embedded documents, and it does not directly
> support the ability to join associated collections together.

Comment: Pretty good Chris... thanks for this immediate response. -Uday